# Selecting everything in a table... with a where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an interesting situation where I'm trying to select everything in a sql server table but I only have to access the table through an old company API instead of SQL. This API asks for a table name, a field name, and a value. It then plugs it in rather straightforward in this way:

```
select * from [TABLE_NAME_VAR] where [FIELD_NAME_VAR] = 'VALUE_VAR';
```

I'm not able to change the = sign to != or anything else, only those vars. I know this sounds awful, but I cannot change the API without going through a lot of hoops and it's all I have to work with.

There are multiple columns in this table that are all numbers, all strings, and set to not null. Is there a value I can pass this API function that would return everything in the table? Perhaps a constant or special value that means it's a number, it's not a number, it's a string, *, it's not null, etc? Any ideas?

Comment: SQL injection might be something you should look into.  Assuming you're allowed to do the things you want to do.  Otherwise, you might be doing something illegal.

Comment: I concur. If this API would allow to modify parameter to alter logic of the statement, it would allow deleting from or dropping the table

Comment: You can try to produce `WHERE 1=1` assigning `FIELD_NAME_VAR` to `1` (or any other constant) and `VALUE_VAR` to `1` (the same constant). Depending on how your API implemented it may or may not work.

Comment: the injection attack could be ' OR 1 = 1 --

Comment: @peterm: `[1]` refers to a field called `1`, not a constant

Comment: @Andomar I assume he's trying to sugges `WHERE 1 = 1 AND .. ` other conditions

Comment: Have you tried leaving both fields blank?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing worked and I'm just going to have to jump through hoops to get something added to the API (it's an internal company API developed a while ago).  The brackets around the field name and the single quotes around the value made all of these fail.  Martin Smith's idea below would have worked, but there was a function that used the table name and gave an error when it couldn't find the table in the database.  Thanks all for the help!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Scratch that.  dnoeth added a an answer after I posted my last comment that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to pass this VALUE_VAR

```
1'' or ''''=''
```

If it's used as-is and executed as Dynamic SQL it should result in

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE fieldname = '1' or ''=''
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Seems so simple that I don't know why I didn't think of it!  This worked!  Thanks!

Comment: @dallin - The fact that this actually works shows the API is not constructed correctly and is open to potentially more malicious SQL injection such as `DROP TABLE` statements.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks.  I was thinking this question could be used as a reference for possible sql injection attacks!  Luckily, in my case, this is an internal company API that shouldn't be open to the public to try these attacks.

Answer (score 5):

No this isn't possible if the API is constructed correctly.

If this is some home grown thing it may not be, however. You could try entering `YourTable]--` as the value for `TABLE_NAME_VAR` such that when plugged into the query it ends up as

```
select * from [YourTable]--] where [FIELD_NAME_VAR] = 'VALUE_VAR';
```

If the `]` is either rejected or properly escaped (by doubling it up) this won't work however.

Comment: This didn't actually work for me, but it would of if the API didn't run the table name through a function first that throws an error if it can't find the table. It was definitely the best bet, as the brackets around the field name and the single quotes around the value made all the other suggestions fail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example, 
hope it might help

```
declare @a varchar(max)
set @a=' ''1'' or 1=1 '

declare @b varchar(max)
set @b=('select * from [TABLE_NAME_VAR] where [FIELD_NAME_VAR]='+@a)
exec(@b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your API allows column name instead of constant,

```
select * from [TABLE_NAME_VAR] where [FIELD_NAME_VAR] = [FIELD_NAME_VAR] ;
```

Comment: If this is allowed and the column `[FIELD_NAME_VAR]` is not nullable, it will indeed return all rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, the FIELD_NAME_VAR is enclosed by single quotes, not brackets.  This sadly made this approach not work, as it converted the value to a string rather than a column name.